# Is it possible to set color of texts in dialog boxes of Applescript?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, applescript

Is there any way that the text's color inside a dialog box of Apple script can be changed???

Please reply

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a way to change the text color in a AppleScript dialog box. However, you can change other aspects such as displaying an icon, making the text field display the letters as bullets (for things like passwords), etc. See [AppleScript Wiki](http://applescript.wikia.com/wiki/Display_Dialog#Parameters) for more info.